# Excel macro for converting fix length text file to delimited separated with substring function

Tags: vba, excel

this is the code i am using and its working fine but  for one row only .I need to make it generic to apply it on all rows of the text file.I have total 150 rows in text file.How can i loop it while making next line as end of record.

Code:

```
Public Sub Convert_TxtFile()
Dim myStr As String
    myStr = FileText("C:\Users\BS255028\Desktop\Book2.txt")
    Cells(1, 1) = Mid(myStr, 1, 4)
    Cells(1, 2) = Mid(myStr, 5, 3)
    Cells(1, 3) = Mid(myStr, 8, 8)
    Cells(1, 4) = Mid(myStr, 16, 2)
    End Sub

    Function FileText(ByVal filename As String) As String

    Dim nFileNum As Integer

    If Len(Dir$(filename)) = 0 Then
        Err.Raise 53
    End If

    nFileNum = FreeFile
    Open filename$ For Binary As #nFileNum
    FileText = Space$(LOF(nFileNum))
    Get #nFileNum, , FileText
    Close #nFileNum

    End Function
```

Comment: Use `Split(myStr, vbCrLf)` (or whatever the newline separator is) to split your file content into an array of lines, then loop over that array and process each line similar to what you're already doing for the first line. Increment the row in Excel for each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply record a macro of you importing the text file.  Using fixed widths will allow you to split the text into columns based on the desired widths.

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;C:\Users\BS255028\Desktop\Book2.txt", _
    Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "adam_styborskis_pauper_cube"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(4, 3, 8, 2)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
Public Sub Convert_TxtFile()
    Dim myStr As String, s, arr, i As Long 
    myStr = FileText("C:\Users\BS255028\Desktop\Book2.txt")
    arr = Split(myStr, vbCrLf)
    i = 1
    for each s in arr
        Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 4) = Array(Mid(myStr, 1, 4), Mid(myStr, 5, 3), _
                                        Mid(myStr, 8, 8), Mid(myStr, 16, 2))
        i = i + 1
    next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how `FileText` works, but if it puts the text in to 150 rows in Excel, you can just add a loop:

```
Public Sub Convert_TxtFile()
Dim myStr As String
Dim i as Long

myStr = FileText("C:\Users\BS255028\Desktop\Book2.txt")
For i = 1 to 150
    Cells(i, 1) = Mid(myStr, 1, 4)
    Cells(i, 2) = Mid(myStr, 5, 3)
    Cells(i, 3) = Mid(myStr, 8, 8)
    Cells(i, 4) = Mid(myStr, 16, 2)
Next i
End Sub
```